# How to send keys using post method Google App Engine, NDB?

Tags: google-app-engine

I am new to GAE. I have following model

```
class Course(ndb.Model):
    user = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=User)
    code = ndb.StringProperty()
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    join_date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

And, I have following HTML to save course:

```
   Student: <drop down select field>
   Course Code: <input field>
   Course Name: <input field>
   Joined Date: <input field>
```

I am wondering what should be the value in dropdown select field of Student. Like:

```
<option value={{user.key}}>{{user.first_name}}</option>
```

Or

```
<option value={{user.id}}>{{user.first_name}}</option>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [url safe](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities#retrieving_entities) version of the key.

```
<option value="{{user.key.urlsafe()}}">
```

(This assumes you're using Jinja templates: if you're using Django's, drop the `()`). And don't forget to wrap the value in quotes.